# Почему на апи 23 и выше service останавивается через 5-10 минут?

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение у которого  есть служба. Эта служба получает данные, всё ок работает, но вот после 5 минут служба засыпает. Отчего это может быть? На Android API меньше 23 проблем нет, всё ок, а на API выше 23 вот такой курьёз.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Comment: doze mode, например?

Comment: @post_zeew скорее всего пойду поинтересуюсь что это такое и кка с ним бороться)))

Comment: @temq как не крути этот doze mode дошел до мня )))))))э

Comment: @temq может скажешь как с этим бороться?)

Comment: нашел нашел надо через настройки )

Comment: у приложения есть возможность запрашивать эту настройку самому. я приводил код здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612959/193715

Comment: @tse я был молод я был глуп)))тогда я незнал о чем речь )проблема была в другом ) щас уже врос до нее)))СПасибо!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тебе необходимо дать ему разрешение работать в фоне. Примерное решение(зависит от телефона и оболочки):
 Настройки телефона -> Приложение -> "Необходимое приложение"
Как-то так...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]